# How does ASCII value work internally?

Tags: c

Please use this code as reference by telling how it is giving ASCII output

```
int main()
{ 
char c;
printf("Enter a character: ");
scanf("%c",&c); /* Takes a character from user */ 
printf("ASCII value of %c = %d",c,c); 
return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

Comment: We can't read for you! You have to read for your own! See ^

Comment: I'm just stunned that you ask such a question on here..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is there.

Comment: Don't b stunned..if you know the answer you should be in a position to answer it in simple terms...everyone knows about ASCII, I just wanted to know the internals...

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
printf("ASCII value of %c = %d",c,c);
```

will show the value of `c` in two ways. Firstly as a character, secondly as a number.

Whether or not it is an ASCII value, depends on what `c` is, because the ASCII standard does not encompass *all* of the 256 values representable by `char` or even `unsigned char`. That depends on system settings such as code page, language, etc. Moreover, not all of the ASCII characters are even printable - but some terminal or console outputs will use a printable representation of the number rather than using it as a control - although `7` might ring your bell!